# How to add Meta Tags to the Specials page

Tags: opencart, meta-tags, opencart-3

I would like to add a meta tag and meta description to the specials page ( .../index.php?route=product/special ). could anyone assist?

I'm using OpenCart 3.0.2.0

I did how ever figure out how to add a description to the page but not a meta description nor meta keywords like the categories and products.

Any info would be appreciated.
Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Edit this file:

```
catalog\controller\product\special.php
```

Find:

```
$this->document->setTitle($this->language->get('heading_title'));
```

Add After:

```
$this->document->setDescription('My description...');
$this->document->setKeywords('my, keyword');
```